# 'as if I had' versus 'as if I have'

Tags: grammar, subjunctives

Must I use past tense after *"as if"/"as though"*?

For example:

> *I just don't want to help him. It's not as if I **had** no money.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Books claims 17,300 instances of [*it's not as if I had*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22it%27s%20not%20as%20if%20I%20had%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl), and 11,700 of [*it's not as if I have*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22it%27s%20not%20as%20if%20I%20had%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22it's%20not%20as%20if%20I%20have%22&tbm=bks), which I think suggests that the short answer for OP is "both tenses are fairly common" in such constructions.

Note that the "refuted" statement *("I have money")* can be expressed as *"I am rich"*, where it's easier to see how the *[irrealis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrealis_mood#Subjunctive) (not real, counterfactual)* mood can be conveyed by a "subjunctive" verb form...

> *Even if I **were** rich I still wouldn't help*

Note that in practice many native speakers today would use ***was*** rather than ***were*** there - but in neither case is there any suggestion of *past*. Also note [this example](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22swollen%20as%20if%20I%20had%20cancer%20in%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)...

> *...my throat feels swollen **as if I had** cancer in it; my guts feel as if I had cancer in them too.*

...where clearly the speaker/writer is talking about an "unreal" situation ***now***, not in the past.

---

In practice, most native speakers probably *would* use present tense in OP's specific example, if only to reflect the preceding *I **don't** want to help*. But there's nothing wrong with using the *subjunctive*, which in this case looks just the same as the past tense anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There are many uses of *as if* in English. It can be used as a *slang, comparison, conjunction, and exclamation* etc.

The doubt you have is about using a present tense or past tense with *as if.* The past tense is common when you use *as if* for comparing things/people where **comparison is not true.**

> He's behaving as if he were the king of the world.

In your example, it's used as *conjunction* where it'll mean ***like*** or ***as though***. The past tense is not required.

> I don't just want to help him. It's not as if I **have** no money.

[My source for this answer is here.](http://www.englishteachermelanie.com/grammar-as-if-a-conjunction-and-an-exclamation/) The article talks about the uses of *as if* in English.

Comment: I think "I don't just want to help him" and "I just don't want to help him" aren't the same (so it's unclear to me which one the OP really wanted to use). Also, in your king of the world example, it's better to use "as if he were". I believe that your source would agree with me on that.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Agree to the second point. In fact, I meant 'were' only. Corrected. Thanks.

Comment: *Was* is okay too—the realis-irrealis contrast has been eroding for centuries—but *were* is probably still preferred in formal usage.  Generally, both *was* and *were* can express unreal meaning, while *was* can also express real meaning.  But there are a few fossilized phrases where *were* is either required or occurs much more commonly than expected: *were I to* absolutely requires *were*, while *if I were* has an unusually strong preference for *were*.  So the choice is complicated by a number of factors.